# Machine Learning Vison - Sequence Length setting for CNN +LSTM approach

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have few events which are captured by cameras at certain timestep. These events are having sequences of images representing that entire event. I need to feed these sequence of images to ConvLSTM for clsassification of events, Thus I am currently having the problem in setting uniform sequence length for all events.I do not want use skip/ignore images as my sequence is just having an average of 55 frame and i loose out information if i do that. Can I pad np.zeros((64,64,3)) images to each events so that all events can be of same sequence length. Or do you suggest any other methodologies like pad_sequences?

32 events having number of images in sequences representing those each event is given below.

[50,
67,
54,
64,
63,
53,
53,
31,
136,
36,
30,
31,
29,
31,
38,
46,
49,
65,
47,
44,
75,
55,
35,
29,
31,
41,
35,
33,
33,
131,
197,
62]

I am expecting the dimension as ( 32, sequence length, 64,64,3) to ConvLSTM model.
where 32 are the events, sequence length is the length of event with number of images that are sequence,64*64 image size, 3 is for RGB channel.
so how shall fix my sequence lentgh now.

Comment: "having the problem in setting uniform sequence length for all events" - What does this look like? / What have you attempted this far?

Comment: I am getting the shape as (32, 20, 224,224,3)  where the  20 in the shape refers to the sequence length. But in the problem, i am having varaible sequence lengths.  i didnt define any number for it to give me as 20, then why it is showing me 20. not able to undestand. does Pad_sequence will help me?